# how to compare 2 lists for equality

Tags: c#, .net

even if value in dow and dy are equal,it doesnt enter inside the loop to check equality

```
foreach (DayOfWeek dow in daysofweek)
{
    foreach (day dy in cleave.WeekDays)
    {
        if (Mode == 1)
        {
            //textBoxnumofdays.Text = Convert.ToString(span.Days+2);
            if (dow.Equals(dy))
            {
                textBoxnumofdays.Text = Convert.ToString(span.Days - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                textBoxnumofdays.Text = Convert.ToString(span.Days + 2);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //textBoxnumofdays.Text = Convert.ToString(span.Days + 1);
            if (dow.Equals(dy))
            {
                textBoxnumofdays.Text = Convert.ToString(span.Days - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                textBoxnumofdays.Text = Convert.ToString(span.TotalDays + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void Getdays()
{
    DateTime dtFrom = new DateTime(dateTimePickerfromdate.Value.Year,
        dateTimePickerfromdate.Value.Month, dateTimePickerfromdate.Value.Day);
    DateTime dtTo = new DateTime(dateTimePickertodate.Value.Year,
        dateTimePickertodate.Value.Month, dateTimePickertodate.Value.Day);
    daysofweek = new List<DayOfWeek>();           
    cleave = new LeaveApplication(constr);         
    while (dtTo != dtFrom)
    {
        dtFrom = dtFrom.AddDays(1);
        daysofweek.Add(dtFrom.DayOfWeek); 
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `cleave` here? and what is `daysofweek`? and what is `day`

Comment: cleave is the object of class and daysofweek is the object of list DayOfWeek        daysofweek = new List<DayOfWeek>();           
                 cleave = new LeaveApplication(constr);

Comment: Oh, there are so many things @Marc didn't know.

Comment: what is **Cleave.WeekDays** How is it populated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are trying to check if its a weekday or not

```
foreach (DayOfWeek dow in daysofweek)
{
}
```

So just compare it with like `dow == DayOfWeek.Sunday` and accept or ignore based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Because for each `daysofweek` it will do a full cycle of `cleave.WeekDays`, so it will probably activate first the `if` part and in the next cycle the `else` part. What are you trying to do?

Comment: iam trying 2 compare 2 lists so that i can get days which are common in both of the lists

Comment: But then you are writing a SINGLE "response" to the textBoxnumofdays (each time you overwrite the past "response")

Comment: day (used by dy) is not a DayOfWeek, so dow.Equals(dy) will probably be false (unless you overloaded Equals, but I don't think you did it)

Comment: so please tell me  how to convert a list of type day to DayOfWeek

Comment: I don't even know what a type "day" is, how should I tell you how to convert it? What is the type day? It isn't a "standard" type.

Comment: Just for the record: You should use Pascal Case for your custom types (here it should be Day)